# Unable to extract CSS from scss with ExtractTextPlugin webpack

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-2, extracttextwebpackplugin

I have following configurations in my webpack.config.js and package.json respectively:

```
var extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: '[name].css', disable: false, allChunks: true});


module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: extractSCSS.extract(['css','sass'])
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    extractSCSS
]
```

and

```
"css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^2.2.0",
```

But I am not able to generate the css files. Is there something I am missing here?

**EDIT**
I updated the files as below:

```
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
"sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
```

and

```
{
     test: /\.css$/,
     exclude: /(node_modules)/,
     loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
        loader: "css-loader",
        publicPath: "/dist"
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `sass-loader`

```
npm install --save-dev sass-loader
```

Note that with Webpack2 you should/have to update the configuration file :

- It is not possible anymore to omit the -loader extension when referencing loaders ([Automatic -loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed))
- `module.loaders` is now `module.rules` ( [webpack 2 migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules) )
- [chaining loaders](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#chaining-loaders) is only supported using the legacy option `module.loaders`
- in V2 `rule.use` entry specifies a loader to be used. ([rule.use](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use))

Here is extracts of my working config :

```
const extractCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('app.bundle.css');
```

add this rules :

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: extractCss.extract([
        { loader: 'css-loader', query: { sourceMaps: true }},
        { loader: 'sass-loader', query: { sourceMaps: true }}
    ])
},
```

and the plugin :

```
plugins: [
    extractCss,
```

Comment: Ok, So I installed sass-loader, updated the webpack.config file but still css file is not being generated. Also when I tried installing `extract-text-webpack-plugin@beta` it says unmet peer dependency for node-sass@^3.4.0 | | 4.0.0, but I have installed node-sass.

Comment: Your updated config target css files ( `/\.css$/` ) instead of `.scss`  and there is no sass loader...

Answer (score 1):

I have `ExtractTextPlugin` set up and it works, but it looks totally different from the configuration that you have. This is my configuration

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                loader: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }),
            test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/
        }
        ...
},
plugins: [
    ...
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        allChunks: true,
        filename: "style.[contenthash].css"
    })
    ...
]
```

How it works is that the loaders get called from the back to the front. So first is the `sass-loader`, then the `postcss-loader`, etc. The `fallbackLoader` option is used when there is no CSS which can be extracted.

Last but not least, I want to add that I don't use `ExtractTextPlugin` in development, since it can result in longer build times.

**Edit**

I forgot to include the plugins part of my configuration. And just to clarify, the dots mean that there it is a piece of my configuration. All content relevant to the question is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but for me moving over from Browserify I had some grief with this same issue.

I didn't realise in order for the ExtractTextPlugin to produce any css, I had to include the scss in the javascript *somewhere* (even though it's extracting to app.bundle.css or similar) otherwise it will silently produce no output.

application.js

`require('../scss/container.scss')`

or

`import css from '../scss/container.scss'`

will result in injected `<style>` tags in the header in development, and an extracted `app.bundle.css` file in production.